# rigid body method name expected?

Tags: c#, methods, vector, rigid-bodies

I'm really new to this but I keep getting method name expected error with this.

public float speed;

```
void Start () {
    rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(Random.Range (-100(speed * Time.deltaTime)), (100(speed * Time.deltaTime)), Random.Range (-100(speed * Time.deltaTime)), (100(speed * Time.deltaTime))));
```

I have no idea if it I've just got messed up brackets or if the I'm just not allowed to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do multiplication like that in C#, you need to explicitly give an operator:

```
Random.Range(-100 * (speed * Time.deltaTime))
```

etc.

The error message is because text immediately followed by brackets is interpreted as a method call, but `100` is not an existing (or even valid) method name.